# OnTouchListener doesn't record ACTION_UP when navigating to another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener

While holding down *button* with one finger and I navigate to another Fragment with a different finger, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP doesn't fire after lifting my finger in the next fragment or at all.

```
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { _, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {             // PRESSED
            doAction(true)
            return@OnTouchListener true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {                // RELEASED
            doAction(false)
            return@OnTouchListener true
        }
    }
    false
})
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

try to catch `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` action also, `ACTION_UP` means that user intentionally removed finger from `View` and in your case finger is still there (touching screen), but framework will probably dismiss/cancel all `MotionEvent`s when leaving `Fragment`/destroying `View`